# Finding AD Distro Group samaccountname with email address

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to move a few hundred AD distro groups to a new OU.  I was given their email address only, and wanted to make a script to move them based on samaccountname.  I am wondering why the below does not return anything, if I do the groups one-off filtering for email address it works, but foreach returns nothing.

The "groups.txt" listed below is just a list of email addresses.

```
gc groups.txt | % {
  Get-ADGroup -Filter {mail -eq "$_"}| Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes you have around `$_`.

```
gc groups.txt | % {
  Get-ADGroup -Filter {mail -eq $_}| Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
}
```

In your posted filter script block the variable is quoted. Since it is a script block, PowerShell doesn't do any processing first and the ActiveDirectory module expects a variable not surrounded in quotes. That would look for `Mail` that is literally `"$_"` and not the email address value of the variable.

Comment: Thanks Bentek!  Any insight as to why?  Is it because if the @?

Comment: Can you please explain this answer ?

Comment: Edited and explained.

Answer (score 2):

Take the "" off of `$_`

```
gc groups.txt | %{ Get-ADGroup -Filter {mail -eq "$_"} | select -expandproperty samaccountname}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this answer ?

Comment: In the filter function, `-Filter {mail -eq "$_"}` is telling the system to filter where the email address matches whatever is inside the `""` which is a string, as opposed to just looking for the line variable of `$_`.  That's my understanding, anyway.  The `""` make it look for a string instead of a variable.  If you know better, feel free to chime in here.